# How does argparse's add_argument take variable length arguments before keyword arguments?

Tags: python, argparse

In python2.7, the argparse module has an add_argument method which can take a variable number of unnamed arguments before its keyword arguments as shown below:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='D')
parser.add_argument('-a', '-b', ... '-n', action='store', ... <other keyword args>)
```

As far as I know, function definitions as follow don't work:

```
def fxn(var_args*, action, otherstuff):
def fxn(action, otherstuff, var_args*): # results in conflict on action
```

What is the proper means to emulate the `add_argument` behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's argument definition order is...

1. Required and/or default-value arguments (if any)
2. variable-length positional arguments placeholder (`*<name>` if desired)
3. keyword arguments placeholder (`**<name>` if desired)

The positional arguments placeholder gets a list, the keyword arguments placeholder gets a dict.

`add_arguments` simply looks for keys in the dict of keyword arguments, rather than spelling out all of the possible arguments in the declaration. Something along the lines of...

```
def add_arguments(*posargs, **kwargs):
    if 'action' in kwargs:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass arbitrary number of arguments to a function.

Here is an example

```
def f(x, *args, **kwargs):
    print x
    for arg in args:
        print arg
    for key, value in kwargs:
        print key + ': ' + value
```

Reading this will help: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments.